# React + Redux App: Calling API through a Redux action Vs Calling an API directly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a React+Redux application. I'm calling APIs through Redux actions and storing the response data in the Redux state. But there is a case, Where I don't have to store the API response data in the Redux store.

> So the question is, Is there any valid reason to call the APIs through
>   Redux actions or Should I call the APIs directly since I'm not storing
>   the response data in Redux store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of call you're trying to make, and who's concern it is.
Here are a few cases:

- Is this a one-way call to track something?. You can fire an action that gets picked up in a `middleware`. this is a good case for sending analytics.
  This doesn't have to be stored in Redux's store.
- Is this a call where some other part of your application will need this data?, then this is a good use case for making an update in the Redux `Store` so other components when read this  and use props to decide what to render etc.
- Is this a call where it only concerns one component or isolated part?. You can make this call inside the component in `componentDidMount` since this doesn't concern anyone else

Alternatively take a look at [Sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), they observe all actions that get dispatched and decide what to do with them in a clean way.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer quite well explains the scenario where from API call can be initiated. For better user experience, we always show some `spinner` or `busy sign` to inform the user that a request is being made and it has not finished yet. It may happen that **API response** is not mutating the state, but to let the user know some task is going in the background, we usually update `store` (for global access) or `state` (for component level access) with value like `isFetching` or anything meaningful.

So, it depends on the developer, whether he/she want to show some `busy` sign or silently perform the API request. Moreover, if they want to show `busy` sign then, they should decide which part of the application should be aware of the API call. If it is restricted to the component level only, then no need to make the call in `actions`, otherwise, for global level, yes it should be inside `action`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer!

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of uniformity, you should always follow the redux way, even though all the responses are not stored in Redux. It is also a question if you are not using the response from an API call why are you making the call. This argument is counter-intuitive. If you are using the response in some way better do it the Redux way. It is advised to always store the response to a call to Redux and use it, I am sure you are making API calls to do some action on UI.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer!